# pass multiple variables to PHP

Tags: php, var

I have a PHP page which accepts two variables

```
<?php 
    $formurl = "listen.html" ;
    $playerurl = "player.php" ;

    $mymp3 =  $_POST["mp3name"]; 
    $mytitl = $_POST["titlname"]; 

    /* echo "MP3 Name: ".$mymp3."<br>" ;
    echo "Chapter Name: ".$mytitl;  */
    header( "Location: $playerurl?mp3name=$mymp3& ?titlname=$mytitl");
    exit ;
?>
```

but when I open player.php,

```
<table width="519" border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <?php
            $mymp3=$ _GET[ "mp3name"];
            $mytitl=$ _GET[ "titlname"];
        ?>
        <td width="513" height="63" class="TopNav" align="center">You are listening to
            <?php echo $mytitl; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <audio autoplay controls preload="auto">
                <source src="/MP3s/<?php echo $mymp3; ?>.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
                <source src="/MP3s/<?php echo $mymp3; ?>.mp3" />Your browser does not support the audio tag.</audio>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
```

only one variable (`mp3name`) gets displayed. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
header("Location: $playerurl?mp3name=$mymp3& ?titlname=$mytitl");
```

should be

```
header("Location: " . $playerurl . "?mp3name=" . $mymp3 . "&titlname=" . $mytitl);
```

the first query string key starts `?` and the rest start with `&`.

I have added the spaces and `.` (concetenation) to make it easier to read (not required)

[Wikipedia link to info about the query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

**Update**

As @ernie pointed out in the comments ... [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) does this for you ... and encodes the paramters .. you use it like this :

```
$params = http_build_query(array('mp3name' => $mymp3, 'titlname' => $mytitl), '', '&');
header( "Location: " . $playerurl . "?" . $params);
```

Comment: My answer may not get seen due to yours being voted up, but it's probably better to use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php), rather than trying to manually build the query string

Comment: @ernie if you can explain why *it's probably better* then I will +1 yours ;-)

Comment: added a few notes about why to use the function, as well as how using Firebug or other dev tools to see the query data would help

Answer (score 3):

Your GET string needs to be corrected, i.e.:

```
header( "Location: $playerurl?mp3name=$mymp3&titlname=$mytitl");
```

It'd probably be better if you used [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to avoid such errors.  http_build_query will handle all the formatting of the arguments (that is the names, key-value generation, and separators), so as long as you have a valid array, you'll get a valid query string, e.g.:

```
$getString = http_build_query(array ( 'mp3name'=>$mymp3, 
                                      'titlname'=>$mytitl));
header( "Location: $playerurl?$getString);
```

You could also use the console view in FireBug (or similar tools in Chrome and IE) to have helped debug this on your own, as they would allow you to see the actual data being sent/received.

Comment: you might want to remove the last comma for the array ... and you missed the biggest reason to use the function ... encoding

Comment: In general, I tend to keep the trailing comma when writing arrays on multiple lines, as it makes it easier to add new key/values.  I'll go ahead and remove for clarity.

Comment: Also note in the comments of the `http_build_query` function that its better to use `http_build_query($array, '', '&');` to ensure the separator is `&` rather than `&amp;`

Answer (score 0):

```
header( "Location: $playerurl?mp3name=$mymp3& ?titlname=$mytitl");
```

Should be:

```
header( "Location: $playerurl?mp3name=$mymp3&titlname=$mytitl");
```

The `titlname` variable isn't being passed in properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have the header wrong. Take out the space with ? It should be

```
header( "Location: $playerurl?mp3name=$mymp3&titlname=$mytitl");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following:

```
urlencode("$playerurl?mp3name=$mymp3&titlname=$mytitl")
```